# Product sku in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, grid, php-7

I have created custom grid using ui component.

I want to add product sku column in custom grid which contains product skus list from product table.

How to do that ....

If anyone knows please explain me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Vendor Name : Testing
- Module Name : ABC

> app/code/Testing/ABC/Model/ResourceModel/ABC/Grid/Collection.php

You need to just add code to fetch product sku in `_renderFiltersBefore()` function

```
<?php

namespace Testing\ABC\Model\ResourceModel\ABC\Grid;

use Testing\ABC\Model\ResourceModel\ABC\Collection as ABCCollection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document as ABCModel;

class Collection extends ABCCollection implements \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{
    protected $aggregations;

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = ABCModel::class,
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['product' => $this->getTable('catalog_product_entity')],
            'product.entity_id = main_table.product_id',
            ['product_sku' => 'product.sku']
        );
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
    public function getAggregations()
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }
    public function setAggregations($aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
    }
    public function getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)
    {
        return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($this->_getAllIdsSelect($limit, $offset), $this->_bindParams);
    }
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
    public function getTotalCount()
    {
        return $this->getSize();
    }
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }
    public function setItems(array $items = null)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Note : In your xml file, filter should be working by `product_id`.**

Comment: still I'm not getting @Rohan.............

Comment: can you post your error message?

Comment: Do you fetch records by product id?

Comment: Happy to help!!! Happy Coding :) @PriyaM

Comment: I'll post answer of your second question. Please upvote also in answer. So other user can use this answer.

Comment: Welcome @PriyaM :)

Comment: what to write in form.xml

Answer (score 0):

> add your desired columns in prepareColumns

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
               $collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection()
               ->addAttributeToSelect(
                   'name'
               )->addAttributeToSelect(
                   'sku'
               )->addAttributeToSelect(
                   'price'
               )
        ->addOrder('entity_id', 'asc');
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

            $this->addColumn(
                'in_events',
                [
                    'header_css_class'  => 'a-center',
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'name' => 'in_events',
                    'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                    'index' => 'entity_id',
                    'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                   'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                   // 'use_index' => true
                ]
            );

        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('name', ['header' => __('Name'), 'index' => 'name']);
        $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku'
            ]);
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ),
                'index' => 'price'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'position',
            [
                'header' => __('Position'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'position',
                'editable' => 'false'
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks..But I'm creating ui component grid