# how to display product sku in admin grid

Tags: magento2

everyone, I want to display product SKU in admin grid I am following this link [Product sku in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/218976/product-sku-in-magento2) now I want to know what to write in the index.xml to pass SKU in admin grid

Answer (score 0):

Follow the `catalog_product` module.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

Find code like below.

```
<column name="sku" sortOrder="60">
     <settings>
         <filter>text</filter>
         <label translate="true">SKU</label>
     </settings>
 </column>
```

Copy above code and past in your **listing.xml** file

**Note :** Above code display only column in admin grid. For display **SKU** value in column you need to add logic in your dataprovider file.

Comment: no result is coming

Comment: column Displaying?

Comment: column is displaying but data is not coming

Comment: Read note in above code.

Comment: can you please provide logic of data provider

Comment: For that you need to follow `catalog_product` module

Comment: can you please provide the path of it